# FTP Server Require SSL Connection

Tags: azure, ssl, ftp, ftps

In Azure, I set up the Windows Server 2012 R2 FTP service properly and have no problems connecting via the standard **Windows 7 FTP client** when the server-side setting is "Allow SSL".  My endpoints are properly defined, etc.

However, when I change the setting to "Require SSL", I am unable to connect.  I set endpoints for FTP SSL ports 989 and 990.  I have a certificate installed properly (bound to HTTPS port 443).  I selected the same certificate for use with FTP.

Note:  When the server is set as "Allow SSL", Filezilla connects using TLS successfully.  Neither FileZilla nor the **Windows 7 FTP client** can connect when the server is set as "Require SSL".

I want to **require** SSL connections when using the **Windows 7 FTP client**.  I do not care about FileZilla (that was just for testing).  I cannot find any walk-throughs or examples where the author uses the "Require SSL" setting on an Azure machine.

Suggestions to fix?